# Collapsing rows with NaN entries in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, nan

I have a pandas DataFrame with rows of data::

```
# objectID        grade  OS     method
object_id_0001    AAA    Mac    organic
object_id_0001    AAA    Mac    NA
object_id_0001    AAA    NA     organic
object_id_0002    NA     NA     NA
object_id_0002    ABC    Win    NA
```

i.e. there are often multiple entries for the same objectID but sometimes/often the entries have NAs.

As such, I'm just looking for a way that would combine on ObjectID, and report the non-NA entries e.g. the above collapses down to::

```
object_id_0001    AAA    Mac    organic
object_id_0002    ABC    Win    NA
```

Comment: Why don't you use `dropna()` with the `subset` arg? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Quick and Dirty

This works and has for a long time.  However, some claim that this is a bug that may be fixed.  As it is currently implemented, `first` returns the first non-null element if it exists per column.

```
df.groupby('objectID', as_index=False).first()

         objectID grade   OS   method
0  object_id_0001   AAA  Mac  organic
1  object_id_0002   ABC  Win      NaN
```

---

#### `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame([d.lookup(d.notna().idxmax(), d.columns)], columns=d.columns)
    for _, d in df.groupby('objectID')
], ignore_index=True)

         objectID grade   OS   method
0  object_id_0001   AAA  Mac  organic
1  object_id_0002   ABC  Win      NaN
```

---

#### `stack`

```
df.set_index('objectID').stack().groupby(level=[0, 1]).head(1).unstack()

               grade   OS   method
objectID                          
object_id_0001   AAA  Mac  organic
object_id_0002   ABC  Win     None
```

---

If by chance those are strings (`'NA'`)

```
df.mask(df.astype(str).eq('NA')).groupby('objectID', as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: Nice! *quick and dirty* indeed ;} (not the down voter, of course)

Comment: @piRSquared okay, interesting. I've just checked the pd.concat method on my real-life datafile that I have, and this runs, but it doesn't chose numerical data over the NaN. I think this is when the row with the NaNs is *before* the row with the data you want.

Comment: Are your `'NA'` actually null values?  Or are they strings `'NA'`?

Comment: Okay. Pretty sure the pd.concat and stack methods work here. Mega-thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This will work `bfill`+ `drop_duplicates`

```
df.groupby('objectID',as_index=False).bfill().drop_duplicates('objectID')
Out[939]: 
         objectID grade   OS   method
0  object_id_0001   AAA  Mac  organic
3  object_id_0002   ABC  Win      NaN
```

Comment: Nice answer (-:

Answer (score 2):

One alternative, more mechanical way

```
def aggregate(s):
    u = s[s.notnull()].unique()
    if not u.size: return np.nan
    return u

df.groupby('objectID').agg(aggregate)

                grade   OS      method
objectID            
object_id_0001  AAA     Mac     organic
object_id_0002  ABC     Win     NaN
```