# PYTHON insert dataframe to an exiting dataframe

Tags: python

I am a beginner at Python. I want to combine some datasets together on a Date column.
I have a dataset like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
d1=date.today()
print(d1)
d2=d1 - timedelta(days = - 1)
print(d2)
d3=d2 - timedelta(days = - 1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [d1,d2], 
                    'number': [100, 200],
                    'a':[11, 12],
                    'b':[21, 22],
                    'c':[31, 32],
                    'd':[41, 42],
                    'e':[51, 52],
                    'f':[61, 62], 
                    'g':[np.nan ,np.nan ]
                   })
df21= pd.DataFrame({'Date': [d3], 
                    'number': [100],
                    'a':[13 ]})
df22 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [d3], 
                    'number': [100],
                    'b':[23 ]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [d1], 
                    'number': [100],
                    'g':[10]})
```

The output datasets:

```
#df1
        Date number a   b   c   d   e   f   g
0   2021-05-31  100 11  21  31  41  51  61  NaN
1   2021-06-01  200 12  22  32  42  52  62  NaN

#df21
    Date    number  a
0   2021-06-02  100 13

#df22
    Date    number  b
0   2021-06-02  100 23

#df3

    Date    number  g
0   2021-05-31  100 10
```

The results I would like:

```
    Date     number a          b    c          d    e          f    g
0   2021-05-31  100 11.0    21.0    31.0    41.0    51.0    61.0    10
1   2021-06-01  200 12.0    22.0    32.0    42.0    52.0    62.0    NaN
2   2021-06-02  100 13.0    23.0    NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
```

However, I tried to use **concat** and **append**, all of them do not give me the desired output.

```
pd.concat([df1,df21, df22,df3], ignore_index=True)
     Date   number  a          b    c          d    e          f    g
0   2021-05-31  100 11.0    21.0    31.0    41.0    51.0    61.0    NaN
1   2021-06-01  200 12.0    22.0    32.0    42.0    52.0    62.0    NaN
2   2021-06-02  100 13.0    NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
3   2021-06-02  100 NaN    23.0      NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
4   2021-05-31  100 NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN     10.0

df1.append(df21, ignore_index=True).append(df22, ignore_index=True)
 
       Date number  a          b    c          d    e          f    g
0   2021-05-31  100 11.0    21.0    31.0    41.0    51.0    61.0    NaN
1   2021-06-01  200 12.0    22.0    32.0    42.0    52.0    62.0    NaN
2   2021-06-02  100 13.0    NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
3   2021-06-02  100 NaN     23.0     NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
```

I had to use Python to combine those tables. Does anyone know how to do this?
I appreciate any help!

Thanks,

JH

Comment: Hi @Jean-Hu if your question has been solved by any answer please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dfs = [df1,df21,df22,df3]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).first()
```

or

```
dfs = [df1,df21,df22,df3]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.set_index('Date').stack().groupby(level=[0, 1]).head(1).unstack()
```

[Collapsing rows with NaN entries in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52899858/collapsing-rows-with-nan-entries-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function. You would do something like:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df21, on="Date", how="outer").merge(df22, on="Date", how="outer").merge(df3, on="Date", how="outer")
```

Since both `df1` and `df21` contain `a` for example, as per the normal join behavior Pandas will duplicate the column and you will end up with something like `a_x` and `a_y` representing either of the two data frames. You can then write a mutation to combine this, like `a = a_x or a_y` (where you can also define how to handle the case when both columns have differing values).

See also the [Pandas cheat sheet](https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf).